# Matlab + Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I'll be very grateful if you'll help me to solve the equation with Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method + Matlab.

**Given:**

$P=\frac{mt}{b+t}$

**Also:**

t=[1,3,4,7,8,10] 
P=[2.1, 4.6, 5.4, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6]

**1)** Write **P** in Matlab.

**2)** Find **b,m** by solving the equation with Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method.

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Write the equation this way
$$\frac{1}{P}=\frac{b}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{m}$$

Comment: Nice trick. Now it's clear. Thank's for you hint!